# How do I color a table to look neutral?

Tags: color, responsive-design, tables

[image]
This is a web table I'm working on!, What tweaks should I do to make it look neutral?

This table is responsive as 2 columns will be displayed on a mobile device, 4 on a tablet and 6 on large displays.

would appreciate any suggestions or guidelines. thanks.

update1:
image when border applied,
[image]
update2:
black one
[image]

Comment: How are you currently considering it "definitely not neutral"? The colors? The sahdes? The font? The text content?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean how the color differences makes your eye focus on some cells more than others, right? Wouldn't the obvious choice be to tone down the color differences, so that nothing stands out too much or use a single color?

Comment: how are the blue shades calculated?

Comment: @Jongware yes the colors.

Comment: @Joonas You got it right. I'll try tuning colors.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve at a communication level? It's unclear what you mean by 'neutral'. Are you saying some of these colors represent positive, some negative and some neutral? We need more details.

Comment: Do you really need to use a background color? There's nice tables that can be created without using all the borders and full background color. Maybe it's my ignorance but I'm not sure to understand or see how the table should be read (horizontally?) I think it's important to make this obvious if there's a relation between the columns and rows. I don't mind trying some tests but I'd need more details on this!

Answer (score 3):

Identify the non-neutral elements of your table and figure out how to fix them.

- the table has an uneven color distribution, with very bright cells and very dark cells, both of which attract attention, and so are not neutral.
- several table cells have the same color, these also draw the eye and brain into finding a connection, and so again, not neutral
- some cells have lots of text, some none, same effect with the colors, and again, not neutral

I would add an outer border and differently styled inner borders to make the table more official looking and hence more neutral.

And neutral colors are typically white/beige/gray, and so consider toning down the overall color scheme.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The design must be locked with blue shades, hence replacing to white/biege/gray cannot be done. have tried adding a border.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents.

1) If you are refering to Joonas coment. You need that some cells doesn't stand out more than others, do not randomize the colors. Do it more mechanical. A Checkboard pattern? The same color for all with a white border in between? The same color each 2 rows?

2) If you refer to context? The blue + the title America at the beguinning looks political or flag-dependent. Inclusive America, Buenos Aires. So, probably you need a gray table.

Comment: Have tried (1) but when on a mobile device there will be only two columns. So one colum goes with single color and the second with another color.  (2) Must stick with the blue shades. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define what *you* think is "neutral". I'm uncertain if you are referring to a neutral color palette or something else. So, I'll assume you mean an palette.

Most often neutral colors elude to greyscale and sometimes beige or tans. The point of a "neutral" palette is that it is **not** vibrant or eye-catching, but rather understated and unobtrusive. Clearly bright blue cells don't fit this, no matter how you arrange them or how much contrast between cells there may be. Your blues are essentially "screaming" at users because they are so bright and vibrant.

You could just drop the saturation of all the colors and get closer to grey values to create a more neutral color scheme:

[image]

You could still keep a "blue" feel to it by just retaining some saturation.... (although I'd probably drop the value of the "America" cell so it's not such a stark contrast.)

[image]

.. nothing too bright or too dark. Everything roughly in the middle of a color spectrum.

Or you could shift things to a warmer neutral by using browns....

[image]

In any event, bright, vibrant colors almost *never* indicate a "neutral" palette.

An easy way to do this is to start with *only* grey values. Color everything grey adding enough variation so that the cells can be independently seen against each other when they are different values, but not so much variation that any of the cells immediately catch the eye (unless you want it to). *then* slowly add the color you'd like to use to the greyscale table. Stop with the color once you get to a point where it clearly looks "tinted" with that color, but still basically a greyscale table.

Trying to do this by changing hex values can be challenging. I'd suggest you use Photoshop and just play with your screenshots as I have until you find an overall color scheme you feel works, then pull hex values from that Photoshop file.

Answer (score 1):

Neutrality has two meanings:

1. A color with low to zero saturation.
2. A lack of differentiation compared to the surroundings.

If you're going for #1, switch to HSB color mode and set S to something under 30.

For #2, you'll have to consider factors crossing hue, saturation, brightness, texture, style, etc. It's a relative measure of an element's uniqueness in it's surroundings. That's not something we can accurately assess without the rest of the view.